# How to configure metadata certificate of my site for ADFS server - working with passport-saml

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, passport.js, saml-2.0, adfs

I'm new to work with NodeJS and was asked to configure SSO to the website I build using SAML with ADFS authentication, considering the fact my company is using AD for our system management. Considering the fact I use nodeJS,
I found that work with passport-saml module will be best for me. I'm looking for
help with the creating of federation metadata xml to send it to my ADFS IDP.
thanks in advance,

DLGM

Comment: You don't need metadata - you can configure it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need metadata - you can configure it manually.

Choose the SAML RP option.

Refer: [Configure strategy for ADFS (SAMLp)](https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2).

So the "realm" is the ADFS RP identifier.

The thumbprint is for the ADFS token signing certificate.

Under "Advanced", set SHA-1.